# Displaying and manipulating data in a windows form, Which control should I use?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display data in a windows form using C# .NET. So that’s good, there are many ways to do that. The data is coming in as a flat text file. Some of the data should be displayed as a single element that stretches across the control (a comment line), while other data should be displayed in a table with many columns. Yet, I want the whole list, including comments, to be displayed in one single list.

My problem is that at this point I am not sure what control I should/could use to display this irregular data, or what approach I should take. What would part of the c# forms controls should I be learning about and planning to use in order to fill my goals. My current candidates are vacillating between ListView and DataGridView. What tool(s) can be used to fill this need where some table rows will be a single column and others will be multiple columns, if any.

Lets say my data looks like this:

```
red       | green    | purple   | blue
comment that is one single piece of data
Foo----------------- | Bar---------------
red-------| green--- | purple-- | blue
one       | green    | purple   | blue
Foo----------------- | Bar---------------
one       | two      | three    | four
comment that is one single piece of data
comment that is one single piece of data
red       | green    | purple   | blue
one       | green    | purple   | blue
Foo----------------- | Bar---------------
one       | two      | three    | four
```

Comment: I think, that before you put any control on canvas you should think about how you will keep such data into system. If you answer that question it will be easy for you to choose something for you. In my opinion you are reaching too deep from GUI level directly to flat text file.

As you mentioned there are different types of data, you probably want to interpret them in different ways, give them some properties, etc. Think about it first, and then connect it to GUI.

Comment: @KrzysztofDziądziak I have revised my question to focus on my stumbling point and provided an example of what the data will look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be very helpful to see the structure of your data. What in the world is a "unified comment - list"? What do you mean by "irregular data"?

Anyway, in my experience, the best tool in Winforms to deal with tabular data is `DataGridView`. You can have combobox cells, image cells. You can easily format and color them, validate and disable when necessary.

---

Edit: more info

What you need is basically some colspan, easibly obtainable in HTML grids. You can't do that easily in DataGridView, quoting the Ms DataGridView program manager

```
The DataGridView does not have any support for merging cells. You can custom paint
content across cells, but apart from that you would have to do a lot of work and
custom coding to produce merged editable cells.
```

but you could buy a 3rd party component ([Telerik GridView](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-overview.html) or similar) or search for a custom implementation like this:

[DataGridVewTextBoxCell with Span Behaviour](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34037/DataGridVewTextBoxCell-with-Span-Behaviour)

Maybe this can be useful too:

[Multi Column Combo Cell for the .NET 2.0 DataGridView Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18330/Multi-Column-Combo-Cell-for-NET-2-0-DataGridView-c)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fea3dcff-5447-450a-8f7c-bb1c4f63371d/merging-cells-in-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols

---

EDIT 3: Ok, if you just need to display your data why don't you try adding in your winform a `webBrowser` component, compose your HTML text and then display it? You can add style, font, colors etc etc like any web page.

Sample

```
private void showHtml()
{
    var htmlstring = @"<html><table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td>Green</td>
        <td>Purple</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan='4'>Comment that is one single piece of data</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>Foo</td>
         <td colspan='2'>Bar</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td>Green</td>
        <td>Purple</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td>Green</td>
        <td>Purple</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <td colspan='4'>Comment that is one single piece of data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </html>";
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = htmlstring;
}
```

[image: http://oi40.tinypic.com/2uygkjt.jpg]

Comment: I have revised my question to focus on my stumbling point and provided an example of what the data will look like. While you are right in what you say, I am sure, I am more interested in the question that was formerly described by me as irregular data

Comment: +1 What about other options. Forget the frills. ListView? Is there an easier way?

Comment: I have to give it to you, and I was thinking of an HTML solution as a possibility but I think I may decide to rethink and revise my requirements/design.